# Save a file via sink function in shiny server?

Tags: r, download, shiny, save, sink

I have a shiny app to generate a `.txt` file to download.
In addition, I would like to keep a copy of the file that users generate in my shiny server.
the server function looks like :

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

data_gen <- reactive({

d1= data.frame(...)
d2= data.frame(...)

result <- list(d1=d1, d2=d2) 
return(result)

})

create_file <- reactive({
 sink("/srv/shiny-server/S3/file.txt",append = TRUE)
 print(data_gen()$d1) 
 print(data_gen()$d2)
 sink()

})

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() {"input.txt"},
  content = function(file) {

      sink(file,append = TRUE)

    print(data_gen()$d1) 
    print(data_gen()$d2)

      sink()
  }
)


}
```

I'm able to download the data but the app does not react to the `create_file` function and it does not write a copy into shiny server.
Any Idea how could I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `create_file` function is a reactive. Reactive functions only evaluate when 1) their output is required, and 2) their inputs have changed. Neither appears to apply here.

What you could do is move the contents of `create_file` inside your downloadhandler. `content` must receive a function that returns a file, but the function can do other things first. So try the following:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

    data_gen <- reactive({
        d1= data.frame(...)
        d2= data.frame(...)
        result <- list(d1=d1, d2=d2) 
        return(result)
    })

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

        filename = function() {"input.txt"},
        content = function(file) {

        # save non-user copy
        sink("/srv/shiny-server/S3/file.txt",append = TRUE)
        print(data_gen()$d1) 
        print(data_gen()$d2)
        sink()

        # copy to be returned for user
        sink(file,append = TRUE)
        print(data_gen()$d1) 
        print(data_gen()$d2)
        sink()
    })
}
```